# How to prevent count up timer from pushing text next to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a count-up timer setup and some text next to it. As the timer increases, the text next to it moves/shakes. I'm trying to prevent that from happening and want to keep them both on the same line. Below are the JS, CSS, HTML codes I've used. All put together at jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/79d8qyvx/

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  var updatesPerSecond = 20;
  var animalsKilledPerYear = {
    "carbon": 7100000000000,
    "chickens": 68785221000,
    "methane": 70000000000,
    "pigs": 1484492840,
    "manure": 335000000000000,
    "fishes": 97398330000000000,
    "water": 11900000,
    "cows": 302128113,
  };

  var secondsPerYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  var interval = 1000/ updatesPerSecond;
  var count = 0, start = new Date().getTime();

  function update(intervalCount) {
    for (var subset in animalsKilledPerYear) {
      var numKilled = animalsKilledPerYear[subset];
      var countElement = document.getElementById("akc-" + subset);
      if (countElement) {
        countElement.innerHTML = Math.round(intervalCount * (numKilled/secondsPerYear) / updatesPerSecond).toLocaleString();
      }
    }
  }

  function selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval() {
    update(++count);
    window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval - (new Date().getTime() - start - count * interval));
  }
  window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval);
});
```

```css
#akc-carbon, #akc-chickens, #akc-methane, #akc-pigs, #akc-manure, #akc-fishes, #akc-water, #akc-cows{
  color: #111 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: oxygen, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span id="akc-carbon"></span> kgs
```

Comment: If you want to stop the wiggle, you might want to add `font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;` It's not going to be perfect, but can help a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a monospace font?

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  var updatesPerSecond = 20;
  var animalsKilledPerYear = {
    "carbon": 7100000000000,
    "chickens": 68785221000,
    "methane": 70000000000,
    "pigs": 1484492840,
    "manure": 335000000000000,
    "fishes": 97398330000000000,
    "water": 11900000,
    "cows": 302128113,
  };

  var secondsPerYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  var interval = 1000/ updatesPerSecond;
  var count = 0, start = new Date().getTime();

  function update(intervalCount) {
    for (var subset in animalsKilledPerYear) {
      var numKilled = animalsKilledPerYear[subset];
      var countElement = document.getElementById("akc-" + subset);
      if (countElement) {
        countElement.innerHTML = Math.round(intervalCount * (numKilled/secondsPerYear) / updatesPerSecond).toLocaleString();
      }
    }
  }

  function selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval() {
    update(++count);
    window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval - (new Date().getTime() - start - count * interval));
  }
  window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval);
});
```

```css
#akc-carbon{
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<span id="akc-carbon"></span> kgs
```

Comment: Simple. Elegant. Works. In fact, monospace gives the counter digits more room, making it easier to read. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following method, you could use a ***parent*** and wrap the ***kgs*** unit in a `span` tag and set its `position` to `absolute` and the ***parents*** `position` to `relative`. You could then get the intervals ***string length*** * the ***font-size***, then set the ***left position*** of the unit position using `akc.nextElementSiblings.left` to the sum of the ***letter.length*** and ***fontSize***. This will push the kgs element over to the ***right*** with a slight space between the intervals string and the unit element.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var updatesPerSecond = 20;
  var animalsKilledPerYear = {
    "carbon": 7100000000000,
    "chickens": 68785221000,
    "methane": 70000000000,
    "pigs": 1484492840,
    "manure": 335000000000000,
    "fishes": 97398330000000000,
    "water": 11900000,
    "cows": 302128113,
  };

  var secondsPerYear = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  var interval = 1000 / updatesPerSecond;
  var count = 0,
    start = new Date().getTime();

  function update(intervalCount) {
    for (var subset in animalsKilledPerYear) {
      var numKilled = animalsKilledPerYear[subset];
      var countElement = document.getElementById("akc-" + subset);
      const akc = document.getElementById("akc-carbon")
      const akcRect = akc.getBoundingClientRect();
      const akcRectTop = akcRect.top;
      if (countElement) {
        countElement.innerHTML = Math.round(intervalCount * (numKilled / secondsPerYear) / updatesPerSecond).toLocaleString();
        // get the length of the letters in the textContent
        let letters = akc.textContent.length;
        // get the computed style set for font-size
        const fontSize = getComputedStyle(akc).getPropertyValue('font-size');
        // get the numerical value of the sum of letters 
        // length and font-size for akc-carbon element
        const compWidth = parseInt(letters * fontSize.split('px')[0]);
        // set the root variable using style.setProperty
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--unit-left',`${compWidth}px`);
        // set the units elements left position to compWidth
        akc.nextElementSibling.style.left = `${compWidth - compWidth / 2 + 5}px`;
        // set absolutely positioned top position to 
        // previous siblings top position
        akc.nextElementSibling.style.top = `${akcRectTop + 1}px`;
      }
    }
  }

  function selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval() {
    update(++count);
    window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval - (new Date().getTime() - start - count * interval));
  }
  window.setTimeout(selfCorrectingTimeoutInterval, interval);
});
```

```css
:root {
  --unit-left: 0;
  --unit-top: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

#akc-carbon,
#akc-chickens,
#akc-methane,
#akc-pigs,
#akc-manure,
#akc-fishes,
#akc-water,
#akc-cows {
  color: #111 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: oxygen, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.unit {
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--unit-left);
  top: var(--unit-top);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span id="akc-carbon"></span>
  <span class="unit">kgs</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed reply. Thank you. But it might be a little too advanced for me who's self-learning.